# How to make an arrow with arrow tip

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to make an arrow with equation of the line at its tip. Whether various style of arrows are available for example a curly arrow etc?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.04,yscale=0.08,domain=0.125:100,samples=400]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (150,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,65) node[left] {$y$};
    \draw[red] plot (\x,{50-0.5*\x});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such arrows go under the name `pin`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.04,yscale=0.08,domain=0.125:100,
    declare function={f(\x)=50-0.5*\x;},
    every pin edge/.style={-stealth,shorten <=0.5pt,black}]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (150,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,65) node[left] {$y$};
    \draw[red] plot[samples=2] (\x,{f(\x)});
    \path (0.125,{f(0.125)}) -- (100,{f(100)})
     node[pos=0.5,sloped,pin={[black]110:{$y=50-x/2$}}]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a touching pin.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.04,yscale=0.08,domain=0.125:100,
    declare function={f(\x)=50-0.5*\x;},
    every pin edge/.style={-stealth,shorten <=-1pt,black}]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (150,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,65) node[left] {$y$};
    \draw[red] plot[samples=2] (\x,{f(\x)});
    \path (0.125,{f(0.125)}) -- (100,{f(100)})
     node[pos=0.5,inner sep=0pt,sloped,pin={[black]110:{$y=50-x/2$}}]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to move the arrow so that it's feet touch the red straight line?

Comment: @user1942348 This is rather simple, I added the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the endpoint simply by adding `coordinate{B}` after the plot commmand. Then, to determine the start point put `x=0` in the equation to get `(0,50)` as point `A`. Using the `calc` library draw the arrow starting at the middle of AB, `($(A)!.5!(B)$)`, and extend it by 10 and 5 in `x` and `y` directions, respectively.

You can choose other arrow tips from the `arrows.meta` library. For other complex curves, there is an option to use the `intersections` library to determine the intersection between your curve and the 45-degree line from the origin to determine the starting point.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.04,yscale=0.08,domain=0.125:100,samples=400]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (150,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,65) node[left] {$y$};
    \draw[red] plot (\x,{50-0.5*\x}) coordinate(B) (0,50) coordinate(A);
    \draw [->] ($(A)!.5!(B)$) -- ++(10,5) node[right]{$y=50-x/2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]